# ASP.NET Core - 502.5 - Process Failure error occurs from time to time (Rapid Fail Protection?)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

We have deployed a ASP.NET Core application on Windows Server 2012 R2. Everything is working except when sometimes the customers experience site crashes with 502.5 - Process Failure error. They have said it stays for 1-5 minutes.

From EventViewer I can see these errors:
`Failed to start process with commandline '".\<appname>.exe" ', ErrorCode = '0x80070002'.`

From the errors in EventViewer I can say that the error occurred twice this weak.

It seems to be a common problem that others also have experience it but I still don't know the reason why it is happening in my case.

We have this application deployed on some other machines and I have never seen that happens.

My guess is that the Rapid Fail Protection feature of the IIS triggers and restarts the pool. It is setup with the defaults - 5 crashed for 5 minutes. I have checked our logs for errors and saw that error a lot:

`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {259b6327-0ab1-4dff-95ed-48f568879fab} was not found in the key ring.`

After following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#create-a-data-protection-registry-hive and did some tests locally (where I also had that) the error is still there.

**Questions:**

Can this be the reason for 502.5 error ? Can I disabled (or extend the crashes count per minutes) the Rapid Fail Protected ? What will happen if I do?